# Include only those in a related ICollection with specific filtering

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext

I have a Bill model which has associated payments and readings associated with it as follows:

```
public class Bill
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 BillID { get; set; }

    .............

    public virtual ICollection<Reading> Readings{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

In my BillsController I have the following code on the index view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        return View(db.Bills.ToList());
}
```

Is there any way at the controller level that I can filter out readings that for instance have a reading value as 0 thus indicating a problem?

Comment: db.Bills.Where(s => s.Readings.Count() > 0).ToList()

Comment: no i am looking for a reading.amount value not this

Comment: I can add a viewmodel class to do it I was just wondering if there was a means of doing this through fluent api on the db context call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I am interpreting your question correctly, but it sounds like you want to select all Bills and only include the readings on that bill if their amount property is greater than 0. If this is the case, the following code should do it for you.

var billsWithFilteredReadings = db.Bills.Include(b => b.Readings.Where(r => r.Amount > 0));

Happy Coding.